# recursion moving char to the end of the string

Tags: java, string, recursion

i need to get a string and rearrange it with recursion by getting char and by that char i have to move that char everywhere on the string to the end 
like "Hello world!" ,'l' => "Heo word!lll"
i have problems understading the recursion way of thinking
so i started with this:

```
public static String ChToLast (String str, char ch){
    if(str.indexOf(ch)== -1){
        return str;
    }else{
        if(str.indexOf(0) == ch){
            return str;
        }
    }
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you explain more about what it is you have to do? It's not fully clear to me.

Comment: recursion basically has two main parts. one, is your ending condition. when do you need the recursion to stop. two is your continue condition, when does the method needs to call itself?

Comment: @NocNit pick a char out of a String, and move all occurrences of it to the end of the String.

Comment: the function is suppose to take a single string and a char and move every char we chose to the end of the string using recursion @NocNit
Thank you for your time

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted. Helps me a bunch too ;)

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me understand this and i learned a lot @NocNit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is the practise of reusing your method inside itself. In this case, I will provide a solution to explain what happens:

```
public static String chrToLast(String str, char ch) {
    //This if statement details the end condition
    if(str.length() < 1) {
        return "";
    }

    String newString = str.substring(1); //Create new string without first character

    if(str.indexOf(ch) == 0) { //This happens when your character is found
        return chrToLast(newString, ch) + ch;
    } else { //This happens with all other characters
        return str.charAt(0) + chrToLast(newString, ch);
    }
}
```

If you execute:

```
chrToLast("Hello, World!", 'l')
```

This will result in the desired result: `Heo, Word!lll`

**Process**

In general, this method works by checking which character is currently the first in the given string, and then deciding what to do. If the first character is the same as the one your looking for (`l`), it will then remove that character from the string and use `chrToLast` on **that new string**. But, it also adds the character it found to the end of the result by using `+ ch`. It continues to do this until there are no more characters left, which is what the **end condition** is for.

**The end condition**

The end condition returns an empty string `""` because that is what is called the *base case* of the algorithm. You can think of a recursive algorithm as something solving a problem by calling itself a number of times. By calling themselves, recursive algorithms move towards a *base*. In this particular case, it does that by subtracting one character off the string each time the method is executed. Once there are no characters left, it reaches the base case which is `""`, where the string is finally empty and no characters can be subtracted anymore. (Hence it returns nothing as it's final state)

I hope this answers your question. It's important to understand this concept, as it is very powerful. Try to study the code and comment if something's not clear.

Something that can also help is by executing this code in an IDE and using the debugger to walk through its execution. You can then see for yourself what the flow of the program is, and see the value of the variables in play.

Comment: why does it return empty string  at the end condition?

Comment: It does that because there is no character to return anymore. It executes the function a number of times, and each time the first character of the string gets removed: `Hello World!` -> `ello World!` -> etc. Once the string is empty, it needs to stop. So instead of continuing, it immediately returns an empty string.

Comment: Updated my answer to add information about the end condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you use recursion, it will be pretty expensive call for the result you are expecting. Lot of movement of String or charArray elements, eitherway you do. I don't see its a wiser choice. I would do it this way, it will be of space complexity O(2n) & performance complexity O(n).

```
public class Solve {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ChToLast("Hello world!", 'l'));
}

public static String ChToLast(String str, char ch) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    char[] modChars = new char[chars.length];
    int i = 0;      
    for(char element : chars){
        if(ch != element){
            modChars[i++] = element;
        }
    }
    Arrays.fill(modChars, i, chars.length , ch);
    return new String(modChars);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***while loop*** and write a method to check if that string means perfect statement then that may work for you
Here you would need some help of NLP concept to check everytime if arranged chars are making any statement or are grammatically correct. 
This will help

Comment: im a newbie and ill do some research on the NLP concept thank you