# remove and add char to string recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, char

How to make the char in the recursion at the end
or example:

`removeChar ("hello world, let's go!",'l')` → "heo word, et's go!llll"

`removeChar("you should not go",'o')` → "yu shuld nt goooo"

```
public static String removeChar(String word, char charToRemove) {
  String char_toremove = Character.toString(charToRemove);
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == charToRemove) {
      String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
      return removeChar(newWord, charToRemove);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(word);
  return word;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use replace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursion moving char to the end of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536852/recursion-moving-char-to-the-end-of-the-string)

Answer (score 0):

Say you call `removeChar("hello ", 'l')`,
you currently remove the `l`,
recursively call `removeChar("helo ", 'l')`,
and simply return that directly.

First, that is not optimal, because it now has to scan the initial `he` characters, that have already been scanned.

Second, don't just return it directly. Add the removed letter to the end, before returning the result of the recursive call.

So, instead of:

```
String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
return removeChar(newWord, charToRemove);
```

You want:

```
String prefix = word.substring(0, i);
String remain = word.substring(i + 1);
String subst = removeChar(remain, charToRemove);
return prefix + subst + charToRemove;
```

Or just in one line:

```
return word.substring(0, i) + removeChar(word.substring(i + 1), charToRemove) + charToRemove;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply
it returns me "o" for "hello,'l' and not "heoll"

did you have any idea why?